# Can I install Ubuntu from a live USB to which I have copied some additional data?

Tags: installation, files, live-usb

I created a live USB for Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit edition around a month ago. The installation went fine from the USB.

I've been adding some files not related to Ubuntu to a folder on the USB drive. I want to know whether I can use the same USB to install the Ubuntu again without removing the files that I have added to the USB in a separate folder.

Comment: No, you don't need to remove your files, just plug it and reboot,it will work (if Ubuntu files are not damaged or deleted by you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can. This is because most of the Ubuntu installation components on the LiveUSB are stored in a single compressed file; as long as that has not been deleted, corrupted or modified you will have no problems. The LiveCD/installer will simply ignore any files that are not within its defined structure, including files you have added yourelf.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a problem. Either way try it, its the best way to be sure.